# SQL view seems to not completely abstract data from the original?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-view

A view was created to pull data and use in multiple reports, vwRPWIP_POST.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    Job, MDescription, MWarehouse, MReference, TrnDate
FROM            
    CompanyE.dbo.WipJobPost AS wjp
WHERE
    (Job LIKE '%P') 
    AND (MWarehouse = 'F') 
    AND (TrnDate > DATEADD(DAY, - 395, GETDATE())) 
    AND (LEFT(MReference, 1) LIKE '[0-9]')
```

It returns the expected data:

[image]

The issue is when folks enter alphabetic characters in the `MReference` column, specifically the first three characters, SQL returns an error when those alphabetic characters are compared to a Julian date (eg 203).

`MReference` usually contains Julian dates with another alphabetic designator and usually looks like 203-MU but will continue to be allowed to hold offending data.  When there is offending data, those records will simply be dropped from the report.

Using T-SQL `LEFT`, I compare 203 to today's Julian date, do a calculation and based on that outcome build a report of the appropriate records. Sometimes `MReference` contains strings like "DUMMY", "SPACERS", "RED-MU", and the like.

So I reworked `vwRPWIP_POST` to only include records where the first column in `MReference` is numeric using the last AND clause in the `WHERE` clause. That works and when I edit all rows in SSMS is see only records where at least the first character is numeric.

The stored procedure is here:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp12DAYRESINREPORT]   
    @parFromDate NVARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FromDate NVARCHAR(5),@Locn NVARCHAR(10) = 'PRES';
    SET @FromDate = @parFromDate;

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.Job, A.JobDescription, A.QtyToMake, A.JobDeliveryDate,
        A.MDescription, A.MWarehouse, A.MReference, A.HierHead1,
        A.OperCompleted, A.WorkCentre, 
        B.LocnSummed QtyCompleted
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             wm.Job, wm.JobDescription, wm.JobDeliveryDate, wm.QtyToMake,
             wp.MDescription, wp.MWarehouse, wp.MReference, wal.HierHead1
        , wal.OperCompleted, wal.QtyCompleted, wal.WorkCentre
        , LEFT(wm.JOB,7) AS MID7
    FROM
        TablesCoE.dbo.vwRPWIP_POST wp
    INNER JOIN
        (TablesCoE.dbo.vwRPWIP_ALLLAB wal
        INNER JOIN
            TablesCoE.dbo.vwRPWIP_Master wm
        ON
            wal.Job = wm.Job)
    ON 
        wp.Job = wm.Job
    WHERE wp.MWarehouse = 'F'
        AND LEFT(wp.MReference,3) <= @FromDate
        AND wal.OperCompleted <> 'Y'
        AND (wal.WorkCentre = 'PRES'
            OR wal.WorkCentre = 'VPRS')
    )A
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT LEFT(JobRel,6)Job,SUBSTRING(JobRel,8,2)Rel
    ,LocnRecordsAggregatedSummed LocnSummed
FROM
    (
    SELECT JobRel,SUM(LocnRecordsAggregated)LocnRecordsAggregatedSummed
    FROM
        (
        SELECT LEFT(matl_nbr,9)JobRel,LocnRecordsAggregated
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT matl_nbr,LocnRecordsAggregated = 1
                FROM mtrk_CompanyE.dbo.trxn_hstd
                WHERE locn_to = @Locn
            )A
        )B
    GROUP BY B.JobRel
    )C
)B
ON
    (LEFT(A.Job,6) = B.Job COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        AND SUBSTRING(A.Job,7,1) = RIGHT(B.Rel COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,1))
WHERE
    LocnSummed <> QtyToMake
    --AND LEFT(MReference,3) <= @FromDate - 10;

END
```

With the changes to the view, lines 18 and 23 no longer error out nor does 38 "AND LEFT(wp.MReference,3) <= @FromDate" in A's where clause.  But when line 68 is uncommented SQL errors with:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp12DAYRESINREPORT, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'P  ' to data type int.

It fails on the first of the "P" `MReference` it encounters, this is the data without the last AND clause in the view so I can pull offending data:

[image]

That last AND clause in usp12DAYRESINREPORT seems to be able to see through the view and get back to raw data and records and does the compare there!?

I tried to do that last comparison in the Access reporting front-end but get #Type! issues when using VAL() to convert the MReference field to string.

Why does that last "AND LEFT(MReference,3) <= @FromDate - 10;" seem to get all the way back to WipJobPost?  Or is that what it is doing?

Here's some data with good and bad records

```
2000410P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY                F   DUMMIES     2020-03-11 00:00:00.000
2033480P    2 5/8" TBI-LIGHT                F   DUMMIES     2020-07-09 00:00:00.000
1939490P    2 5/8" TBI-LIGHT                F   DUMIES      2020-05-19 00:00:00.000
1932751P    2 5/8" TBI-LIGHT                F   DUM         2019-07-24 00:00:00.000
C139930P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   C139930P    2020-06-10 00:00:00.000
C139930P    3 7/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   C139930P    2020-06-10 00:00:00.000
1901300P    1 3/4" TBI LAP-LIGHT W/RESIN    F   94-L        2020-04-07 00:00:00.000
2070150P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   51-P        2020-02-21 00:00:00.000
RD83870P    2 5/8" ALI-LGT W/RESIN          F   365-P       2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
1935170P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   365-P       2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
1970701P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   365-P       2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
1970701P    2 5/8" TBI-HEAVY W/RESIN        F   365-P       2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT Applied fix thanks to David Browne.

The recordset had to be abstracted further than the view apparently does.  Selecting the recordset in a temporary table with only acceptable records accomplished this.  Here's the abstracting code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#vwRPWIP_POST') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #vwRPWIP_POST

SELECT * INTO #vwRPWIP_POST
FROM
(
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Job, MDescription, MWarehouse, MReference, TrnDate
FROM CompanyE.dbo.WipJobPost AS wjp
WHERE (Job LIKE '%P') 
AND (MWarehouse = 'F') 
AND (TrnDate > DATEADD(DAY, - 395, GETDATE())) 
AND (MReference LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]%')
)A
```

With updated FROM clause:

```
    FROM
        #vwRPWIP_POST wp
```

Included the temp table drop check again at the end of the sp.

Comment: An explanation as to why the initial view did not seem to sufficiently abstract the recordset would be greatly beneficial to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
with q as
(
SELECT Job, MDescription, MWarehouse, MReference, TrnDate
FROM            
    CompanyE.dbo.WipJobPost AS wjp
WHERE
    (Job LIKE '%P') 
    AND (MWarehouse = 'F') 
    AND (TrnDate > DATEADD(DAY, - 395, GETDATE())) 
    AND (LEFT(MReference, 1) LIKE '[0-9]')
)
select *
from q
where LEFT(MReference,3) <= 100
```

Which is treated similar to the view.  SQL Server is free to process the WHERE-clause criteria in any order, including applying the critera from the outer query before the ones from the CTE/Subquery/view.

You need to materialize the subquery in a temp table or table variable, or write critera that can be reordered, like:

```
case when LEFT(MReference, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' then cast(LEFT(MReference,3) as int) else 0 end <= 100
```

You could try a criterion that is *likely* to be evaluated first, like

```
AND  MReference between '000-' and '999-Z'
```

but that wouldn't be a guarantee.

Comment: David Brown - So make it only possible to see the data in its own temp table without access to any other data?

Comment: David Brown - Thank you.  So abstracting the records into a temp table then allowed only that recordset to be queried, keeping out offending records from the original raw table.  Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You ensure only that the first letter is numeric, not the first 3 - could that be the problem?

Instead of

```
AND (LEFT(MReference, 1) LIKE '[0-9]')
```

I would use something like

```
AND MReference LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Or if they may be 1 to 3 digits, then I would write a little scalar valued function to return the `INT` value of the first 1 to 3 digits before the '-' and use that one in the view.

Comment: Christoph - yes I added that logic and we were prolly typing at the same time.  Same results though.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to extract the Julian date with a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ExtractJulianDate(@Reference NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@Reference IS NULL) RETURN NULL;
  DECLARE @Token AS NVARCHAR(4);
  DECLARE @DelimiterIndex AS INT;
  SET @Token = LEFT(@Reference, 4);
  SET @DelimiterIndex = CHARINDEX('-', @Token, 2)
  -- Hardcoded to remain fast
  IF (@DelimiterIndex < 2) RETURN NULL;
  IF (@DelimiterIndex = 4) BEGIN
    IF (@Token LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]%') RETURN CAST(LEFT(@Token, 3) AS INT);
    RETURN NULL;
  END
  IF (@DelimiterIndex = 3) BEGIN
    IF (@Token LIKE '[0-9][0-9]%') RETURN CAST(LEFT(@Token, 2) AS INT);
    RETURN NULL;
  END
  IF (@DelimiterIndex = 2) BEGIN
    IF (@Token LIKE '[0-9]%') RETURN CAST(LEFT(@Token, 1) AS INT);
  END
  RETURN NULL;
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT Job, MDescription, MWarehouse, MReference, dbo.ExtractJulianDate(MReference) AS JulianDate, TrnDate
FROM dbo.WipJobPost AS wjp
```

Tests:

```
SELECT 123 AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('123-Foo') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 12 AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('12-Foo') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('1-Foo') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate(NULL) AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('-5-Foo') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('123') AS actual
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS expected, dbo.ExtractJulianDate('Foo') AS actual
```

Comment: And of course you can always optimize that to be executed only once at INSERT time instead of on every SELECT through making the function schema bound and using it in a calculated column that you can even persist and index...